# linux, перенаправление

Tags: linux, bash, sh

Дана команда: ls file1 file2. Файл file1 существует, файл file2 не существует.
Перенаправьте только стандартную ошибку в конвейер, одновременно
записывая номера строк и перенаправьте вывод в файл. Стандартный вывод
должен отображаться на экране.
Имею такой код:

`ls file1 file2 2>error`

Не могу понять, как записать в error пронумерованный текст ошибки.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2>` выделяет ошибки, `>(...)` передаёт их на обработку в другую программу, `nl` - нумерует строки, `> error.txt` - сохраняет их:

> ```
> $ ls script.sh lost.txt deal missing.txt 2> >(nl > error.txt)
> script.sh
>
> deal:
> deal_10  deal_11
>
> $ cat error.txt 
>      1    ls: cannot access 'lost.txt': No such file or directory
>      2    ls: cannot access 'missing.txt': No such file or directory
>
> $
> ```

Answer (score 0):

есть система команд из 2-3 символов, одна из них nl

предложу такой вариант, где sdx.txt - существующий:

```
ls sdx.txt file1 file2  2>&1 1> 2.txt   | nl
```

вывод на консоли:

```
> ls sdx.txt file1 file2  2>&1 1> 2.txt   | nl
>      1  ls: cannot access 'file1': No such file or directory
>      2  ls: cannot access 'file2': No such file or directory
```

вывод stdout из файла:

```
localhost:~ # cat 2.txt
sdx.txt
```

Comment: не совсем правильно сделано, но, думаю, nl вы применить сможете